# How to create modal in Magento 2 admin?

Tags: magento2.4, modal, component

[image]I have a button in cms_page_listing.xml file, I expect opens a modal window with a slide effect, when clicked on it.
what should i do, please help

Answer (score 0):

This post will help you with this.

https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/add-view-button-in-admin-grid-to-open-a-view-page-in-slide-window-in-magento-2/

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks, it's a good solution for action column, I'm trying to put it on the main page button.

Comment: Yes you can use it as a reference - the process will be same I think

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can add jQuery on click event as below code. I used as per my need

```
$this->buttonList->add(
                'savevelocity',
                [
                    'label' => __('Export Velocity'),
                    'class' => 'save',
                    'onclick' => "jQuery('<input>').attr({
                                        type:'hidden',
                                        id:'saveandvelocity',
                                        name:'saveandvelocity',
                                        value:'saveandvelocity'
                                    }).appendTo('#edit_form');jQuery('<input>').attr({
                                        type:'hidden',
                                        id:'poid',
                                        name:'poid',
                                        value:".$item->getId()."
                                    }).appendTo('#edit_form');",
                    'data_attribute' => [
                          'mage-init' => [
                             'button' => ['event' => 'save', 'target' => '#edit_form'],
                             ]
                    ] ,
                ],
                30
            );
```

accept solution if works for you

Comment: Can you tell me the path of the file?

Comment: for me its a "\app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit.php"